# Running browser specific JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery plugin that runs only on Mozilla and Chrome and doesn't run in IE < 10 versions so for that I have to use an alternate plugin. How can I run this script specifically on a browser? I tried this but doesn't work:

```
 <![if gte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    alert("IE 8");
</script>

<p>You're using a recent version of Internet Explorer.</p>
<![endif]>

<![if lt IE 7]>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    alert("IE 7");
</script>
 
<![endif]>

<![if !IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    alert("IE 7");
</script>
<![endif]>
```

Comment: You would have better in most cases to use feature detection regarding your plugin methods not supported on older IE browsers, instead of using any kind of browser detection. For example, you could use http://modernizr.com/

Comment: @Shilly — No it doesn't. "This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 … use feature detection instead." http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Comment: What feature in the browser do you need to use that is not available in Older IE versions? You'd be better off to sniff for that feature and if possible provide an alternative via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//userAgent in IE7 WinXP returns: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
//userAgent in IE11 Win7 returns: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1)
 var detectIEregexp = /MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/ //test for MSIE x.x
else // if no "MSIE" string in userAgent
 var detectIEregexp = /Trident.*rv[ :]*(\d+\.\d+)/ //test for rv:x.x or rv x.x where Trident string exists

if (detectIEregexp.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //if some form of IE
 var ieversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
 if (ieversion>=1){
      alert("ie")
 }
}
else{
alert ("other brower");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your code is wrong, check here

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or higher<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower or equal to 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
According to the conditional comment this is not IE 5-9<br />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```